# Change Leaflet-Control-Window modal content by clicking geojson feature

Tags: leaflet, geojson, popup, modal

I have a leaflet map using [Leaflet-Control-Window](https://github.com/mapshakers/leaflet-control-window) to produce a modal pop-up with dynamic content.

Using their documentation I was able to produce a popup when clicking on features of my geojson file, but I cannot figure out how to change the content of that modal based on my geojson file.

This calls the modal:

```
var geojson = L.geoJson(json_Locations3, {
  style: style,
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature

}).addTo(map)

    geojson.on('click',function(geojson){

      var win =  L.control.window(map,{title:'Hello world!',maxWidth:400,modal: true})
              .content('Info:' + Feature.properties.Comments)
              .prompt({callback:function(){alert('This is called after OK click!')}})
              .show()
});
```

This is a part of my geojson file:

```
var json_Locations3={
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 2001.000000, "Comments": "Laguardia Houses. Filler text and description.", "Address": null }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -73.98707531157136, 40.71279019297274 ], [ -73.990326197834079, 40.710554740197978 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 1002.000000, "Comments": "Essex Crossing", "Address": "236 BROOME STREET" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -73.988559744585103, 40.718138957271904 ], [ -73.988629841437202, 40.718003100250257 ], [ -73.988805496163607, 40.718056044119535 ], [ -73.988939514855289, 40.71779629683828 ], [ -73.98937138176332, 40.717926433649048 ], [ -73.98917121142054, 40.718314400521201 ], [ -73.988867202969402, 40.718222771755336 ], [ -73.988863247936536, 40.718230436389028 ], [ -73.988559744585103, 40.718138957271904 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 1003.000000, "Comments": "Essex Crossing Test Description", "Address": "145 CLINTON STREET" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -73.986825413362538, 40.717732897085796 ], [ -73.987087772457556, 40.717230210278437 ], [ -73.987759556669246, 40.717435703706677 ], [ -73.987494416232039, 40.717949651831589 ], [ -73.986819055387571, 40.717745220879294 ], [ -73.986825413362538, 40.717732897085796 ] ] ] } },
```

Any suggestions? I am really a beginner with javascript and struggling with different solutions, but not having luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put a suggested approach on [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/slead/kq8xzxqb/), based on a simplified version of the [Leaflet GeoJSON demo](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/).

[image]

```
// Create the geoJSON layer without using onEachFeature    
var lightRail = L.geoJSON(lightRailStop).addTo(map);

// Set a listener for the geoJSON layer's click event
lightRail.on("click", function(evt){

   // Read in the Content property once the user clicks on the feature
  var content = evt.layer.feature.properties.popupContent;

  // Insert the Content into the leaflet-control-window
  var win =  L.control.window(map,{title:'Hello world!',maxWidth:400,modal: true})
  .content(content)
  .prompt({callback:function(){alert('This is called after OK click!')}})
  .show()
})
```

(As an aside, I would advise using this plugin with caution when attaching it to a layer like this. I think this could be quite annoying to your users - the standard popup methodology may work better. For example, the modal obscures the feature that was clicked on, making it less useful than a popup with a leader line)